# Alleged serial voting reversed but no suspiciousness of such activity taking place in the past 7 days

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting

I noticed a huge -200 drop on my reputation on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ and I've read it has something to do about someone serial voting on my posts and needed to be reversed but I did not notice any such behavior when you look at the history of votes I got. So I'm thinking, could this perhaps be a mistake?

[image: reputation change screenshot]

I read [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) and it says "the system should automatically detect it and reverse it for you within 24 hours" - but the votes I received "fraudulently" don't add up to 200 even in the past 7 days.

[image: reputation change screenshot]

Comment: See this FAQ: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/335251) And this help center page: [Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says "voting corrected"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)

Comment: “could this perhaps be a mistake?” - Extremely unlikely, they caught someone else serially upvoting your contributions, the user likely was also destroyed in the process. You should view the votes as never being legitimate, so you actually lost nothing, since the user who upvoted your contributions broke the rules by serially upvoting your contributions.

Comment: "the system should automatically detect it and reverse it for you within 24 hours" - but the votes i received "fraudulently" don't add up to 200 even in the past 48 hours, not even the past 7 days.

Comment: There isn't a bug here - the invalidation was made manually by the CM team. But I'll leave it to them to provide any details.

Comment: What makes you think you should be suspended for votes others cast on your posts? Unless it was you casting those votes with sock accounts? @animuson can this please be checked? (In such case, suspension should indeed take place.)

Comment: why should i be suspended? i have been using my account in good faith on this platform since the start. and the downvotes i received for this post don't seem fair as i see a legit case of probable cause for investigating if this was a mistake. nothing is perfect.

Comment: They aren’t downvotes. Someone decided to upvote all your posts. This gave you rep, but is against the rules. So the lost rep is because the upvotes were fraudulent and removed, not due to downvotes.

Comment: @cocomac i mean the 2 downvotes now on my question here

Comment: Oh sorry, I don’t know why people downvoted this, but they aren’t required to explain. Sorry. There’s a number of posts debating if people should be required to explain downvotes. Even though it isn’t mandatory, I’m surprised nobody has. I upvoted it though

Comment: I think these posts often get downvoted as misunderstandings of how the vote-invalidation system works (though such misunderstandings are... understandable, given that we intentionally don't give out too much information about our serial-voting detection/invalidation systems).

Comment: Yesterday I was falsely accused of “going through the front pages of multiple sites and upvoting all of the content visible there.”  Since then almost every vote I've ever cast (most of which were on the Blender SE) have disappeared.  Given that I've not yet heard back on my dispute response I don't want to get into details, but if your q/a are some of those hit by this, hopefully your upvotes will be restored once the mods involved realize they've made a mistake.

Comment: @KickAir8p oh my, sounds horrible. yeah these systems aren't perfect, they are prone to mistakes, just like in any other community, for example, in the gaming space i've worked in, there will always be some users that get incorrectly affected. yes we do fix these issues, but unfortunately there will always be the rest of the users who just need to suck it up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Earlier today, a tranche of upvotes was removed from select sites once it became clear enough (given the available evidence) that they were cast with little-to-no consideration for the content of the posts. Further specific information about this case will stay limited to the moderators of the affected sites and the user(s) directly involved.

Just to clarify, vote reversals **do not** typically mean you've done anything wrong - but I can confirm that's true in this case. You've done nothing to worry about. This vote invalidation affected a decent number of people, and you unfortunately happened to be one of them.

While we  have the ability to remove significant parts of the voting record, it's not a joyous experience for anyone. This type of vote invalidation is uncommon, and isn't done lightly. We weigh both the volume of users affected, and whether the invalidation is as small as we can reasonably make it. (We also routinely consider our confidence in the evidence we have.)

While I can't take questions specific to this case, I'm still happy to clarify questions about general policy - at least, when I'm confident in the answer!

Comment: (Also, a word for anyone worried about their own voting habits -- _Very_ broadly speaking, we invalidate votes to help make sure post scores & reputation continue to reflect post quality. As long as you're taking your votes seriously, no need for concern. Please don't let this stop you from voting actively!)

Comment: thanks for your response. oh well. can't do anything about it. still find it weird that -190 was removed when i only received 50 reputation in the past 7 days. its a bummer XD

Comment: @DowJones - The other votes might not have been recent.  The CMs can invalidate all votes by casted by a user. That would mean any vote casted between Feb 16 2022 and when the user last submitted a vote earlier today (at least for you).

Comment: I had also received serial voting. It's fixed now.